# Crash on pushViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push a ViewController, but my app crashes every time.

I'm using the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to take a picture, and once the picture has been taken, this code runs:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage

    // Reset the cameraButton and Tabbar
    self.cameraButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "camera-button"), forState: .Normal)
    self.cameraButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.alpha = 1

    let realmImage = Image()
    realmImage.imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage, 1.0)

    let birthmark = Birthmark()
    //birthmark.imagesArray = RLMArray()
    birthmark.imagesArray.addObject(realmImage)
    birthmark.bodyPart = Birthmark.Bodypart.LeftArm

    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.addObject(birthmark)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemViewController") as! ItemViewController
    secondViewController.existingItem = birthmark
    navigationController!.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, it always crashes on the last line:

```
navigationController!.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

XCode says: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x100489474)

Do you have any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Here's what my storyboard looks like:
[image]

The stack trace:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Why are you asking the navigation controller to present the second controller. Why not use `self.presentViewController`?

Comment: An exception is being thrown. Resume the program execution and let it crash so that the error message is printed out to console.

Comment: When using presentViewController, the navigation bar and tab bar disappear...

Comment: It crashes - the console prints out "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I think it crashes on unwrapping navigationController. It doesn't crash when replacing "navigationController!" with "navigationController?", but then it doesn't present the view controller either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your `navigationController` is `nil`. Forcing it to unwrap using `!` will then result in a crash. Make sure that `navigationController` is not `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think too. I just don't understand how the navigationController can be nil

Comment: @PæturMagnussen In which controller are you? We can't see the context for the method.

Comment: You were right. I wasn't actually in a navigationController which is why it was nil. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know the problem is solved but in my case: I was copied a button from one controller storyboard to another, and the button outlet was copied with it to new controller and caused the crash.

Answer (score 0):

my advice try to push new view controller in dismissView compliation,

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
     let secondViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemViewController") as! ItemViewController
     secondViewController.existingItem = birthmark
     navigationController!.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
});
```

Comment: I think it should call picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated